# Getting events from a dynamically created rectangle object c#

Tags: c#, events, object

I am currently trying to assign an event handler to dynamically created rectangle objects.
These objects are created in a loop based on data within an array e.g.

```
for(int a = 0;  a < array.getlength(0); a++)
{
   //draw rectangle on each iteration
   rectangle shape = new rectangle();

   shape.width(200);
   shape.height(50);

   shape.posTop(posx);
   shape.posLeft(posy);

   posx = posx + 20;
   posy = posy + 50;

   //code to draw onto Canvas object etc...
}
```

is there anyway to assign a mouse click event to each iteration of this object so I can retrieve information about each?

Comment: Is there a definition of an event Click on Rectangle class? if not and it's your class, you should add a public event that you could attach to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried it with something like this

```
for(int a = 0;  a < array.getlength(0); a++)
{
   //draw rectangle on each iteration
   rectangle shape = new rectangle();

   shape.width(200);
   shape.height(50);

   shape.posTop(posx);
   shape.posLeft(posy);

   posx = posx + 20;
   posy = posy + 50;

   shape.click.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(shape_MouseDown);

   //code to draw onto Canvas object etc...
}
```

When I remember right shapes have no click event, but other mouse events like mousedown.

Comment: Hmmm, when I try that nothing happens when I try to fire the event. It will fire If i try and call the event from the form but not the shapes